# Equivalent of ASP.NET Core HttpContext.GetTokenAsync() in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

In ASP.NET Core, I can get the Access Token created by IdentityServer4 as follows:

```
var context = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
var accessToken = await context.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
```

But, when I try to do that in an ASP.NET MVC, `currentContext` is null and when I use `HttpContext` from `System.Web.HttpContext`, it does not have the `getTokenAsync()` method.

It seems like the Authorize attribute in Asp.Net MVC application I have is defined in `System.Web.Mvc`, and the Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core application is defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`.

Could that be an issue?

Any tips on how to retrieve the Access Token in the ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: In .NET Core and .NET Framework, or in ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET 4.x? Please be explicit in the terms you use.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto updated the question

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to use ASP.NET Core's HttpContext in an ASP.NET MVC application? That's completely, utterly wrong and it will never, ever work. Even referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.* NuGet packages in an ASP.NET MVC application is completely wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is why I am asking the equivalent in .net framework

Comment: But the JwtBearerOptions class is also meant for aspnetcore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbeareroptions?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: See https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)/Startup.cs#L73  for adding tokens to cliams . That should work with IDS4 .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access token in your ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) app you need to set `PreserveAccessToken` flag when setting up authentication.

f.e.

```
public static void UseIdentityServer(this IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://localhost:5000",
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "MyApiResourceScope" },
        ClientId = "MyApiResourceName",
        ClientSecret = "MyApiResourceSecret",
        PreserveAccessToken = true,
    });
}
```

Then you can access your token through claims like that:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestGetToken()
{
    var token = ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst("token")?.Value;

    return Ok();
}
```